# Linux Software for testing GUI application via rDesktop

Tags: linux, automation

I'm looking for an automation testing software that run on Linux Debian (Lenny). I'm aware of Sikuli-IDE, but it's a pain to install on Lenny. LDTP wont't work in KDE

The goal is to test a SAP application which is launch on a Windows Server via rdesktop

All the testing process is already implemented (frequency, , measures, reports) and all I have to do is finding the good tool :-)

Comment: I think Windows GUI testing across RDP (especially at the level rdesktop supports it) is likely to be orders of magnitude more difficult than running a native Windows macro utility, like Wintask Pro for example. In the later case you have the option to address windows and widgets by their titles and labels, access the text output directly. In the former case I'd be surprised to hear you have anything beyond absolute mouse positions within a window, and rendered bitmaps to OCR... Even if the RDP protocol would support more, you'd have to rewrite rdesktop to take advantage of this.

Comment: @Szocske Thanks for answering. So, do you think it's possible to invoke a wintask pro (which I don't know) "test suite" via rdesktop using the -s option (remote shell invocation) then make the results written to a shared filesystem ?

Comment: I googled a bit and RDP is actually pretty similar to X11, and an automatable client should be possible, and I'd be interested to hear if one exists :-)

Comment: I used wintask pro 10 years ago, there must be multiple windows macro and test automation tools out there to choose from, some are bound to meet your criteria.

Answer (score 2):

You could write some sort of server in AutoIt or python, then connect to that instead of over RDP.

Comment: Testing via RDP is mandatory for me. That would have been a valuable point though, thanks